# mysql select query. Collect prices for some types in every year

Tags: mysql, sql, pivot

I have this table of prices

```
type | year | price
===================
A    | 2002 | 200
B    | 2002 | 120
C    | 2002 | 126
B    | 1999 | 100
A    | 2004 | 202
A    | 2005 | 206
```

I need a `SELECT` query to produce 2d array of prices of type `A` and `B` in every year they appear, having `NULL` if there is no data for the given type.

```
year | price A | price B
========================
1999 | NULL    | 100
2002 | 200     | 120
2004 | 202     | NULL
2005 | 206     | NULL
```

Comment: You can't do this if you want to have potentially *n* columns where *n* is the number of distinct types.  You *can* have a price A and price B column but that is probably not what you want.

Comment: I have been fetching data in a loop for every type and processing it in php. But it becomes too complicated.

Comment: I need only some types (It's for a plot - user selects max 3 types at a time)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is basically a `PIVOT` but MySQL does not have a `PIVOT` function so you can replicate it using a `CASE` statement with an aggregate function.  If you have a known number of `type` values, then you can hard-code the values:

```
select year,
  avg(case when type='A' then price end) PriceA,
  avg(case when type='B' then price end) PriceB
from yourtable
group by year
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/631e6/5)

Result:

```
| YEAR | PRICEA | PRICEB |
--------------------------
| 1999 | (null) |    100 |
| 2002 |    200 |    120 |
| 2004 |    202 | (null) |
| 2005 |    206 | (null) |
```

If you have an unknown number of `types` then you can use a prepared statement:

```
SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
    CONCAT(
      'avg(case when type = ''',
      type,
      ''' then price end) AS Price',
      type
    )
  ) INTO @sql
FROM yourtable;

SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT year, ', @sql, ' 
                  FROM yourtable 
                   GROUP BY year');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/631e6/4)

Comment: That's a beautiful solution.  +1 for solving a problem I didn't know had a solution.

Comment: Hey Bluefeet, I wonder why you have used `MAX`... I guess the time I was doing the solution, I didn't see requirement of MAX in his question ;) Alright, the source data is different I reckon.

Comment: Can I get AVG of prices in the same year with this method?

Comment: @bonCodigo If you do not use an aggregate function it will not work, if there are multiples for the same year.  - [your version](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8150d/1) with no aggregate and the data altered slightly -- now [my version](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/da37f/1) which works

Comment: @spajak yes, you can use any aggregate including `AVG()`. See my edit.  You can use `SUM()`, `AVG()`, etc.  The `MAX()` will only return the one value, depending on your need another aggregate might be better

Comment: One more thing. If I want to also count all types in a year do I have to repeat the case statement? count(case when type='A' then price end) AS CountA. Is it ok?

Comment: @spajak If you want to add a field to `count` each `type`, then you can use the following -- see this demo -- http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/631e6/6 -- but yes, you will repeat the `case` with a slight change to the syntax -- `sum(case when type='A' then 1 else 0 end) CountA`

Answer (score 1):

---

### ANSWER COMMENTS

---

**THE FOLLOWING ANSWER IS ONLY ANSWERING THE PIVOT - PORTION OF OP'S QUESTION**
As it's not using any aggregations functions, the query is not providing full answer to tally OP's expected output.

Check the reference out :)

[SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/75163/3)

Query:

```
SELECT t.year,
         (CASE WHEN t.type = 'A' 
               THEN PRICE ELSE NULL END) AS price_a,
         (CASE WHEN t.type = 'B' 
               THEN PRICE ELSE NULL END) AS prioce_b         
FROM tbl t
GROUP BY t.year
;
```

Results:

```
YEAR    PRICE_A     PRIOCE_B
1999    (null)     100
2002    200       (null)
2004    202       (null)
2005    206       (null)
```

Comment: Can someone please tell me why you have down-voted my answer? The only differece in the code is that it's not taking an aggregate function into consideration. That is already discussed with Bluefeet above. Other than that, the logic is correct. :( Unfair unfair :(

Comment: I am guessing that it is because it does not return the correct result. Did you look at the result of your query versus the result that the OP requested?  It is not correct this is due to the fact you are not using an aggregate function to determine the correct value.  Your `PriceB` column does not return the right values.

Comment: Thanks :) Did you notice that OP's source table has no 1991 where as his results has 1991? I just used his source table as it is...But I believe it's a typo. The most important part here WAS PIVOT VIEW, then he added up the AGGREGATION, as I later read the comments below the question. Anyways learn something at the cost of -2 ;)

Comment: regardless of the typo, your query doesn't work and that is probably why you got a downvote

Comment: I do agree with you in terms of aggregation point of view. I am now more curious do the pivot **without aggregation.** and to get correct results, because rationally, there's no need to use aggregations and it's just the way the engine works, isnt it? Thanks for the lights :)

Comment: @bonCodigo if you don't place an aggregate and you use a `GROUP BY` MySQL selects just the first record there is no way to predict the result, the aggregation along with the `group by` forces the engine to select the correct value.